# How can I see what attributes are applied to property in code?

Tags: .net, debugging, attributes

Basically the question is in the title: how can I check what attributes a class's property has? For example such attribute:

```
[SomeAttribute()]
public double Hours;
```

How can I see during debug that `Hours` has attribute `SomeAttribute`?

Comment: Using reflection. Did you try searching?

Comment: @CodeCaster, thanks for the tip - I will try reflection.

Comment: It helped me, thanks!

Comment: to all the downvoters: any comment on downvoting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple helper extension method that will be executed only when debugging => this method will write the output to the debug window

```
static class Extensions
{ 
    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static void ShowAllProperties(this object obj)
    {
        var type = obj.GetType();
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Classname: {0}", type.Name));
        var properties = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            //true will show inherited attributes as well
            var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(true);
            foreach (var attribute in attributes)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("'\t{0} - {1}", property, attribute));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

wich can then be called by other classes for instance in their Constructor.

```
class Book
{
    [XmlElement("Author")]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    public Book()
    {
        this.ShowAllProperties();
    }
}
```

this will also work with inheritance

```
class ComicBook
: Book
{
    [XmlElement("ComicBookGenre")]
    public string ComicbookGenre { get; set; }
    public string ComicBookPublisher { get; set; }
}
```